# How to ask someone to only repeat single word instead of sentence?

Tags: questions

I don’t know why this kind of questions haven’t been asked. Sometime when we have a interview with employees, they could say words or jagons we are unfamailiar with or we don’t know meanings.
Imagine I hear everything they said but a single word. I could come up with this situation like:

> Interviewer : Can you explain how JAXB related to RESTful web API?
>   Me : a question [situation where I don’t hear the word JAXB and don’t know how to spell and speak JAXB]
>   Interviewer : I mean JAXB. J. A. X. B. Java Architecture for XML Binding.
>
> Interviewer : Can you mention what tools are required to test your web API?
>   Me : a question [situation where I don’t hear the word test.]

something like “Could you repeat that again?” could make them speak the sentence again. I want them to repeat and spell the word slowy instead of the sentence in case of the jargon. I want them to repeat again in case of the plain word. But I don’t know how to speak or spell word in case of jargon. How can I ask them to repeat and spell words again?

Answer (score 1):

One strategy might be to repeat the question back, and substitute the word **what** for the word(s) that you didn't catch.

> Interviewer: Can you explain how JAXB is related to RESTful web API?
>
> Me: Excuse me, I didn't catch the whole question. Can I explain how **what** is related to RESTful web API?

Comment: This should work. It has a slight chance of making the interviewer think you don't know what JAXB is, as opposed to simply not having heard the word.